# Aliased imports are not supported anymore when creating a new typescript react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, alias

I created a new React-typescript app via this command with `react@17.0.2` and `typescript@4.5.2`:

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

Then I decided to define the alias path as I did many times before. I created the `tsconfig.paths.json` in the root of my app.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["/components/*"],
      "routes/*": ["/routes/*"],
      "constants/*": ["/constants/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I added the `extend` property to the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Also, I installed `react-app-rewired@2.1.8` and created the `config-override.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config) {
    config.resolve = {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
            ...config.alias,
            'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/*'),
            'routes': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/*'),
            'constants': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/*'),
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

So I reopened my IDE (VSCode) and ran `npm start`. I must mention I changed scripts in the `package.json` before running the start command.

```
{
 .
 .
 .
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  }
 .
 .
 .
}
```

After running the start command, this message was displayed in a terminal, and compiling failed:

*The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
-compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)*

*Failed to compile.

./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components' in .......*

So I started to search about this issue to resolve it. I found many approaches, that I will mention some of them below:

***1.*** Go to your `jsconfig.json` file and add the base URL to be "."

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": ".",
   ...
```

Then you can directly import stuff from the src directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```

**Result ==> DID NOT WORK!**

***2.*** This problem is solved by an alias for rewiring. Install `react-app-rewire-alias` then create `config-override.js` file:

```
     const {alias, configPaths} = require('react-app-rewire-alias')

     module.exports = function override(config) {
      alias(configPaths())(config)
      return config
     }
```

**Result ==> DID NOT WORK!**

***3.*** Using `craco@6.4.1` package

1. Install [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco) and [craco-alias](https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias) `npm install @craco/craco --save` and `npm i -D craco-alias`
2. Create `tsconfig.paths.json` in the root directory

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "baseUrl": "./src",
           "paths": {
              "@components/*" : ["./components/*"]
            }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extend `tsconfig.paths.json` in `tsconfig.json`

   {
   "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
   //default configs...
   }
4. Create `craco.config.js` in the root directory

   ```
   const CracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

   module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        {
           plugin: CracoAlias,
           options: {
              source: "tsconfig",
              // baseUrl SHOULD be specified
              // plugin does not take it from tsconfig
              baseUrl: "./src",
              /* tsConfigPath should point to the file where "baseUrl" and "paths" 
              are specified*/
              tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.paths.json"
           }
        }
     ]
   };
   ```
5. in `package.json` swap `"start": "react-scripts start"` with `"start": "craco start"`

**Result ==> DID NOT WORK!**

I'm confused because I had used the alias path many times before, but it does not work now. I don't want to `eject` my app but using the alias path is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to make it work all together (typescript + eslint) in Typescript CRA created just few days ago. This is how I did it:

Selected deps from `package.json`:

```sh
# react: 17.0.2
# eslint: 8.6.0
# react-scripts: 5.0.0
# eslint-import-resolver-babel-module 5.3.1
```

### Install module resolver

```
yarn add eslint-import-resolver-babel-module --dev
```

### Configuration

#### tsconfig

> I don't have any `tsconfig.paths.json`

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...youCompilerOptions
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

#### webpack

Create new file or add to existing `webpack.config.js`

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx"],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
    },
  },
};
```

#### eslint

Finally `.eslintrc.json`

```json
// .eslintrc.json
{
  // ...yourConfig
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src"],
        "alias": {
          "components": "./src/components"
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Here is a work around

Path alias are no longer supported.

But to avoid annoying import paths like `../../../` you can directly import files relative to the `src` directory

**You can do the following**

go to your `tsconfig.json` file add base URL to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

Then you can directly import stuff relative to the `src` directory

```
import utility from "src/Myfile.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your React app was created using `create-react-app` and TypeScript template, I confirm the following steps working as expected with minimum configuration.

1. Install dependencies for configuration override

   ***Using npm***

   ```
   npm install -D @craco/craco craco-alias
   ```

   ***Using yarn***

   ```
   yarn add -D @craco/craco craco-alias
   ```

   `package.json`

   It should look similar to this

   ```
   { 
     // ... 
     "devDependencies": {
       "@craco/craco": "7.1.0",
       "craco-alias": "3.0.1"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create `craco.config.js` at the root level of the project, the same level as `tsconfig.json`

   ```js
   const cracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       {
         plugin: cracoAlias,
         options: {
           baseUrl: ".",
           source: "tsconfig",
           tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
         },
       },
     ],
   };
   ```

   ***Note***

   The `baseUrl` in the `craco.config.js` should match with the `baseUrl` in the `tsconfig.json`
3. Create path alias in `tsconfig.json`

   Below is the typical `tsconfig.json` auto-generated by CRA. Then, add `paths` property inside `compilerOptions`.

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
       "allowJs": true,
       "skipLibCheck": true,
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
       "strict": true,
       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
       "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
       "module": "esnext",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "isolatedModules": true,
       "noEmit": true,
       "jsx": "react-jsx",
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "paths": {
         "@/*": ["src/*"]
       }
     },
     "include": ["src"]
   }
   ```

   `@/*: ["src/*"]` means it will replace path prefix `@/` with `src/`.

   Assuming you have a component named `MyComponent` that is exported using named export from `./src/components/my-component.tsx`, you can import the component using import alias as

   ```js
   import { MyComponent } from "@/components/my-component";
   ```

   which will be converted into

   ```js
   import { MyComponent } from "./src/components/my-component";
   ```

   behind the scene. You can also create new aliases by adding extra properties in the `paths` object of `tsconfig.json`
4. Next, replace `react-scripts` with `craco` in the `scripts` of `package.json`

   ```
   {
     "name": "my-app",
     // ...
     "scripts": {
       "start": "craco start",
       "build": "craco build",
       "test": "craco test"
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```
5. Finally, test the import alias

   ***Using npm***

   ```
   npm run start
   ```

   ***Using yarn***

   ```
   yarn start
   ```